# Rename upload images during upload

Tags: uploads

I want to insert newpost on Front-end of wordpress.
And i want to rename images name during upload **for my code below** 
Result like: "MemberUpload_*dd/mm/yy*_random_number_[width]x[height].jpg" 
(For all size: thumbnail, medium, large, full and custom size)
My code upload i'm using for my theme..

Thanks friends verymuch! ;)

```
// Upload 
if (!function_exists('wp_generate_attachment_metadata')){
                    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
                    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
                    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
                }
                 if ($_FILES) {
                    foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
                        if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                            return "Upload Err: " . $_FILES[$file]['error'];
                        }
                        $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file, $newPost );
                    }   
                }
                if ($attach_id > 0){
                    //and if you want to set that image as Post  then use:
                    update_post_meta($newPost,'Uploaded_img_id',$attach_id);
                }
// END upload
```

Comment: you can't put slashes in a filename, it is a path separator. see [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/93995/rename-attachments-during-upload) for a potential answer.

Comment: @Milo : It's not work for me at front-end posting :(
It only Work when i'm upload picture in Dashboard.

Comment: This post may help you 

[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/93995/37854

Comment: Your syntax is bad.

Answer (score -1):

I think You need to Know about using PHP to upload files as well

[PHP File Upload](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)